# How to add up a sum of a variable number of integers created by a for loop?

Tags: c++

Okay, I'm not really sure the question above really illustrates my problem, but I've spent hours searching for an answer. Basically, I'm creating a dice rolling program that will ask the user to input the number of dice rolled, the number of sides on the dice, and then display the results. However, I also want to be able to add the total of all the rolls. I'm not sure how to do that, though.
Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int roll, side, dice, i;
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout << "      D I C E      " << endl;
    cout << "    R O L L E R    " << endl;
    cout << "*******v1.00*******" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of dice you wish to roll.   " << endl;
        cin >> dice;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of sides on the dice.       " << endl;
        cin >> side;
        cout << endl;
            for (i = 0; i < dice; ++i) //Increments for the number of dice rolled.
            {
                roll = rand() % side + 1; //Allows for variable sides based on input.
                cout << endl;
                cout << "[" << roll << "]" << endl; //Rolls are displayed in a
                cout << endl;                       //column in brackets.
            }
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: `int sum = 0;` and then `sum += roll;` inside the loop. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Define sum variable as 0 and keep on adding it with roll and display it on screen as below.

```
int rollSum = 0;
cout << endl;
do
{
    cout << "Enter the number of dice you wish to roll.   " << endl;
    cin >> dice;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter the number of sides on the dice.       " << endl;
    cin >> side;
    cout << endl;
        for (i = 0; i < dice; ++i) //Increments for the number of dice rolled.
        {
            roll = rand() % side + 1; //Allows for variable sides based on input.
            rollSum += roll;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "[" << roll << "]" << rollSum << endl; //Rolls are displayed in a
            cout << endl;                       //column in brackets.
        }
} while (true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just introduce a variable which accumulates all the rolls:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int roll, side, dice, i;
    srand(time(0));
    cout << "-------------------" << endl;
    cout << "      D I C E      " << endl;
    cout << "    R O L L E R    " << endl;
    cout << "*******v1.00*******" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter the number of dice you wish to roll.   " << endl;
        cin >> dice;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the number of sides on the dice.       " << endl;
        cin >> side;
        cout << endl;
        int total = 0;                          // <<<<<<<<<
        for (i = 0; i < dice; ++i) //Increments for the number of dice rolled.
        {
            roll = rand() % side + 1; //Allows for variable sides based on input.
            total += roll;                      // <<<<<<<<<
            cout << endl;
            cout << "[" << roll << "]" << endl; //Rolls are displayed in a
            cout << endl;                       //column in brackets.
        }
        cout << "total =" << total << endl;     // <<<<<<<<<
    } while (true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay, so += will continue adding as the for loop runs a number of times. I think I get it now. It certainly worked, thank you.

Comment: Sure - you can do this inside or outside the main loop, depending on exactly what you need, but you get the general idea.